# What is the use of rsa_get_blinding?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I don't understand why in **RSA_eay_private_encrypt** and  **RSA_eay_private_decrypt** we need that **rsa_get_blinding** because I'm doing a raw RSA and the function rsa_get_blinding need **RAND function** is **rsa_get_blinding is important or not** ?

Comment: What is your question?  Without any context, whether or not something is important can't be answered.

Comment: i need some information and the real use of the function rsa_get_blinding

Comment: Why are you doing raw RSA?  That is almost always a mistake.  (If your answer is "this is a classroom exercise", then you probably should be using a generic arbitrary-precision math library, such as [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/), instead of OpenSSL.)

Comment: i'm trying to do a RAW RSA in order to implant that code on microprocessor beacause i already did the RAW SHA256 and AES256 now i need to finalize with RSA. And in the RSA part the function rsa_get_blinding need RAND function i dont know if i remove that part will be an issue. That's why i need to know if rsa_get_blinding is a needed function or not

Comment: Everything is important, it's not done just for fun. Blinding is performed to defend against side channel attacks.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  What cryptographic protocol will this RSA implementation be used for?  Is there any way you could possibly arrange to use OAEP in this protocol, instead of raw RSA?

Comment: i m trying to do a RAW RSA in order to have only what i need to work because i ll replace the random part with another randon function that we did. yes i can do it with OAEP padding. i have to do some benchmark with RAW RSA and RSA PKCS1 PADDING. I did the benchmark with the PKCS1 PADDING and now i m doing the RAW RSA it can be usefull before implanting on microprocessor. So that's why iasked i didn't understand the real use of rsa_get_blinding.

Comment: That's not the right way to think about security-critical code.  I won't be able to help you any further.